# Filter Column Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

this question will be easy for you I guess - but I'm a Linux "noob".

Given is the output from a Juniper-Router:

```
 PID USERNAME PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME   WCPU COMMAND
 2434 root      96    0 96476K 14180K select   0:05  0.10% jdhcpd
```

Is it possible (I have a shell on the Device) to somehow filter the output to only show the WCPU Percentage? I want to make a script that restarts a service once a threshold is exceeded - but i need only the value itself - not all the "Username, PID" and stuff.

Comment: It's a `ps` command's output right ?

Comment: i used top on the shell - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with **awk**:

```
<Juniper-call> | awk 'NR==2{ print $9 }'
```

The above should print a value like:

```
0.10%
```